Fuji RAF thumbnails
I am not getting thumbnails for fujifilm RAF images.
I tried adding to /usr/share/thumbnailers/gdk-pixbuf-thumbnailer.thumbnailer the entries:
image/x-raf;image/x-fuji-raf;

I quit nautilus and deleted .cache/thumbnails/ but still I don't see thumbnail generation for RAF files.
The file utility recognizes the RAF files just fine:
$ file ~/Pictures/DSCF8520.RAF
/home/bram/Pictures/DSCF8520.RAF: Fujifilm RAF raw image data, format version 0201, camera GFX 50R

OS: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS

Ok, I decided to do something about this, and contribute with Open Source.
I have created raf-thumbnailer which is a very fast thumbnailer and extracts existing thumbnails from the RAF so that Nautilus can preview them.
It generates a PNG thumbnail in 10 milliseconds or so, from 50MPixel raw image.
Binary debian package is available on my PPA.
